# Shortest path in a maze

Tags: computational-geometry

There is a maze, which is nothing but made of $2$ parallel polylines, which looks like a zig-zag road. We have to find the shortest path between the entrance and exit. Any ideas on how to proceed? Does it involve dynamic programming?

The maze can be thought of as follows:

One polyline consists of the set of points: $\{(x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1), \dots, (x_n, y_n)\}$.

The other polyline is: $\{(x_0, y_0+h), (x_1, y_1+h), \dots, (x_n, y_n+h)\}$ where $h$ is a constant.

Assume that you start from any point on the segment $\big[(x_0, y_0), (x_0, y_0+h)\big]$ and end on any point on the segment $\big[(x_n, y_n), (x_n, y_n+h)\big]$.

Comment: So is it really a maze or rather a zig zag road? Could you provide an example image?

Comment: Does the edit answer your question @null ?

Comment: You should draw an example as it is still very ambiguous. How is a pair of zigzags a maze? Is traversal alone the space between lines or is it along the lines themselves?

Comment: I gave you the set of points. just focus on the mathematical definition and not on particular words, it'd be clearer then. And yes, traversal is among the space between the lines.

Comment: This sounds more like an advice on finding an algorithm. It might be worth asking at [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is covered explicitly, but definitely recommended for further reading is [THE book on computational geometry](http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/)

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Comment: the contest has ended @JoelReyesNoche

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$\ell_0= (x_k,y_k)_{0\leq k\leq N}$$ with $x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_N$ be the lower rim of the corridor, held fixed in the sequel, and drawn in red in the following figure. The upper rim, drawn in blue, is congruent to $\ell_0$, and at time $t=0$ coincides with $\ell_0$. On the red $\ell_0$ mark all $\wedge$-vertices red, and on the blue $\ell_0$ mark all $\vee$-vertices blue.
We shall translate the upper rim slowly upwards, such that at time $t$ we have
$$\ell_t= (x_k,y_k+t)_{0\leq k\leq N}\quad(0\leq t\leq h)\ .$$

[image]

Denote by $\gamma_t$ the shortest path through the corridor at time $t$. When $t>0$ is almost zero then $\gamma_t$ will pass through all marked vertices $V_k$; furthermore $\gamma_0$ has a $\wedge$ at all red vertices and a $\vee$ at all blue vertices. As $t$ is increasing the $\wedge$s as well as the $\vee$s become less outspoken, and some of them even will become straight. When such an event happens $\gamma_t$ will be uncoupled from that vertex $V$, which  then falls out of consideration definitively.

This happens as follows: Assume that an "active" vertex $V_k$ has at least one neighbor of the other color. There are several cases to consider, but it will be sufficient to describe the following case: At time $t$ we have a red vertex  $V_{k-1}=(x_{k-1}, y_{k-1})$ and blue vertices  $V_k=(x_k,y_k+t)$, $V_{k+1}=(x_{k+1},y_{k+1}+t)$. Since $V_k$ is active we have
$${y_k+t-y_{k-1}\over x_k-x_{k-1}}<{y_{k+1}-y_k\over x_{k+1}-x_k}\ .\tag{1}$$
When $t$ increases the left side of $(1)$ will increase, and the right hand side will remain constant, since both $V_k$ and $V_{k+1}$ are blue. There will be a certain value $\tau_k>t$ when equality is reached. This value $\tau_k$ is a rational function of the data appearing in $(1)$.

This leads to the following algorithm:

Put $t_0=0$, $\gamma_0=\ell_0$.

Repeat: Assume that $t_n<h$ and $\gamma_n=\gamma_{t_n}$ have been determined, and all vertices $V_k$, red or blue, of $\gamma_n$ are active. Then find $j:=\arg\min_k \tau_k$, put $t_{n+1}:=\tau_j$, and remove $V_j$ from the stack.

Stop when $t_n\geq h$.

Answer (score 1):

There may well be a slick dynamic programming solution, but I don't know it. Here is one approach that looks like it should work, but I don't quite see how to prove termination. The idea is to model threading a string along the road and pulling it tight. In more detail, find any polyline path contained in the road that connects the end points. Now look for a vertex where you can straighten out the path: i.e., if there are consecutive vertices $u$, $v$, and $w$ such that $|\pi - \angle uvw| > 0$ and such that there is a point  $v'$ on the angle bisector at $v$ with $uv'w$ still contained in the road and with $|\pi -\angle uv'w| < |\pi - \angle uvw|$, replace $v$ by the $v'$ that meets these requirements and minimises $|\pi - \angle uv'w|$. The edges $uv'$ and $v'w$ may now touch vertices on the side of the road and you need to add these as new vertices on the path. Now repeat the process. Each step decreases the length of the path, so if this is a practical problem, you could just stop when it is no longer possible to reduce the length by some given $\epsilon > 0$. I strongly suspect the process must terminate, but I don't see how to prove that just now.

Comment: @VShreyas I think it goes without saying that you are not looking for the trivial answer.

Comment: After yesterday's botched attempts, I hope the above is nearer the mark.

Comment: This is cool. I found out the dynamic programming algorithm though. :)

Comment: Please let us know what the dynamic programming approach is.

Comment: I have tidied up my comments about my botched answer as they don't have any value for posterity. Maybe you could do tidy up too.

Answer (score 0):

Create a weighted graph with distances calculated with Pythagoras (or equal to $h$), and solve using Dijkstra's algorithm or similar.

Comment: I thought it was as simple as that at first, but the weighted graph won't be finite when you deal with cases where you can cut multiple corners.

Comment: Oh, okay. I didn't understand the problem until your comment, so I'll leave this up here

Comment: I guess you could add all the straight lines from every corner to every other corner, and from the start and finish to every other corner and from start to finish, excluding those where the line is not contained in the road. Is there a case where that wouldn't work?

Comment: Ah, but there are infinitely many starting and finishing points. Mmm

Comment: But that can probably be resolved by taking the shortest line between each corner and the starting line segment.